# Lightning slds-hyphenate doesn't hyphenate text

Tags: visualforce, lightning

I'm trying to hyphenate text via lightning's special hyphenate tag **slds-hyphenate** , but it doesn't hyphenate the text. On `visualforce` I just applied `style="word-break: break-all;"` and the text has hyphenated. But lightning ignores it and its own special tag doesn't work for me :( : [Link to slds-hyphenate doc](http://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/components/utilities/hyphenation/)

Not hyphenated lightning text:[image: Description isn't hyphenated.]

Hyphenated visualforce text: [image]

Code for lightning:

```
<apex:page standardController="Account" sidebar="false" standardStylesheets="false" docType="html-5.0">    
  <apex:stylesheet value="{!URLFOR($Resource.SLDSXXX, 'assets/styles/salesforce-lightning-design-system-vf.css')}" />
    <apex:outputPanel>
    <div class="slds">
      <table class="slds-table slds-table--bordered slds-table--fixed-layout">
        <apex:repeat value="{!$ObjectType.Account.FieldSets.TestFS}" var="f">
          <tr class="slds-text-title--caps slds-hyphenate">
            <th id="label" class="slds-text-body">
              <apex:outputText value="{!f.Label}"/><br/>
            </th>
            <td>
              <div class="slds-hyphenate">
                <apex:outputText value="{!Account[f]}"/><br/>
              </div>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </apex:repeat>
      </table>
    </div>
    </apex:outputPanel>
</apex:page>
```

Please, help me hyphenate the text in lightning. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

This feature depends on *browser* support. Depending on your browser, you may or may not see hyphenation. The documentation you linked also mentions that Chrome is having problems right now, a bug has been logged, and it will be eventually fixed. Try your page in Firefox and see if it improves.

Comment: No success, same view in firefox :( Also tried to play around this tag(add/remove to different parts of code) - no changes at all.

Comment: @EvAzi Hey, I forgot to mention: your CSS should be "scoped" to a name you specified when you generated the assets. For example, `<div class="slds mynamespace">`...

Comment: so my code should look like `<div class="slds mynamespace">
      <table class="slds-table slds-table--bordered slds-table--fixed-layout">` ? Should I use the scope somewhere? Changed code as I showed above - no change.

Comment: @EvAzi I'm not saying it'll fix all your problems, but it should be working in [IE, Edge, Firefox, and Safari](http://caniuse.com/#search=hyp), assuming you're using appropriate versions.

Comment: tried it also in I.E. - still the same behavior :( No idea even if the tag doesn't work or my code isn't correct - can't find even find an example of code with this tag.

Comment: Tried to download a new version of sfdl - style has changed, but hyphenation still doesn't work. Also tried to add the tag to the library and load it to static resources - slds didn't render, standard visualforce styles rendered.